# there is a "bad question" on ELL I'm wondering why It's bad

Tags: discussion, questions

I up-voted this question on ELL and the question got down-voted and looks like it's going to be closed. I was told it's a bad question and I shouldn't have up-voted it, why?

> I find the words 'effective' and 'affective' confusing. Most of the
>   times, I fail to use them correctly. When should each of these be
>   used?

Comment: Related:http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1236/9161

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the tooltip for the up-vote button, the guidance says things like "useful and clear" and "shows research effort" and everyone has a little different idea of what that means. Some folks vote based on the "quality" of the question and some folks vote based on how interesting the question is to them. This isn't a very high quality question - it doesn't look like the asker tried to answer their question before posting it here - so I can see that some folks would think it shouldn't be up-voted.

Personally, I would not chide someone for their voting habits. I think everyone should mind their own votes and let other folks vote according to their own conscience. Voting is anonymous for a reason and I think it would have a bad effect on the community if some of us started pushing others into voting the same way we vote. I realize this is a cultural issue though and that some cultures put much more emphasis on people working together as a team while Americans tend to value being independent.

Answer (score 1):

In the original question, adding some examples where the OP was incorrect would allow for a more relevant answer.
Otherwise it becomes an exercise from a dictionary. This relates to "shows research effort" as indicated in the voting button tool tips.